# MemberwiseClone without EntityKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to MemberwiseClone an object retrieved from the ObjectContext without the EntityKey? I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 with C#

If I try to change the Id I get the following Exception:

`The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified`

And if I try to set EntityKey to null:

`The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.`

My code:

```
Offer newOffer = offer.ShallowCopy();
// does not work...
newOffer.EntityKey = null;
/ does not work either...
newOffer.Id = Guid.NewGuid()
this._context.Add<Offer>(newOffer);
this._context.SaveChanges();
```

...

```
public partial class Offer
{
    public Offer ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (Offer)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Does anynone know a simple solution to my problem?

Comment: Try setting the object's state to `EntityState.Added` after copying.

Comment: [Browsable(false)]
[XmlIgnore]
public EntityState EntityState { get; } is it possible to set the EntityState?

Comment: Use the context's `ObjectStateManager` for this.

Comment: Now I'm getting the exception The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MemberwiseClone` copies all members. If you want to avoid copying any member you must make your own cloning. There is a good reason why this is not possible. `EntityKey` uniquely identifies entity and it is immutable. Once it is set you cannot change it and because of that you cannot change any property used to build the key (properties marked as a key in the model). `EntityKey` is also reference type so by creating member wise clone of original entity you would reference the same key instance. Such entity would be useless.